# Pulse duration detection evaluation (opto) LT-22222 from dragino

Tags: voltage-measurement, output, input, logic-level, industrial

My question seems simple but i can't find the answer on documentation. (or I don’t have enough skillz)

I have this energy meter with pulse output:
https://cdn.store-factory.com/www.compteur-energie.com/media/Ketler-KE3205-45A-MID-compteur-energie.pdf
The doc says: EN 62 053-31. (Tension 12-27V DC/ courant <27mA)
Each pulse duration is 30 ms

My inputs are on a LT-22222 from dragino:
https://www.dragino.com/downloads/downloads/LT_LoRa_IO_Controller/LT22222-L/LoRa_IO_Controller_UserManual_v1.5.5.pdf
the doc says:
The DI port of LT-22222-L can support NPN or PNP output sensor. More info page 34. I have make those input works with a simple 24 V generator.

My question is: Can they work together?

Comment: Digital Input ( Detect Low signal , Max, 6V) Yes if you scale to this range

Comment: according to page 34, the doc says that i can input 24v. I dont really understand ... (exemple 2)
"Example2: Connect to a High active sensor.
This type of sensor will output a high signal (example 24v) when active. "

If i understand, you read for LT-33222. Mine are LT-22222:Interface for Model: LT22222-L:
➢ 2 x Digital dual direction Input (Detect High/Low signal, Max: 50v, or 220v with
optional external resistor).
I dont really understand if, LT-22222 can detect 30ms pulse.

Comment: i am also interested in why my question was downvoted :(... i am sorry if i did something wrong. Can you explain ?

Comment: I don’t know , maybe  you can find better manuals or specs on measurements for this

Comment: Downvotes are applied when questions "do now show research effort; are unclear or not useful" - in this case my guess is 'unclear.'

Comment: I guess no one yet has used it and you have to spend time to use Mydevices to connect to TTN to try it out

Comment: Of course i tried ! But i see the input switch with 24v power generator, but with pulse i have doubt. I cant test this for now, because the inputs of LT-22222 are not counted. So, i cant see them. 
TTN and Mydevices are useless, i use the LT-22222-L with private network, and, with pulse of 30MS i can't see the input switch with LORA. 
With simple 24v generator, the inputs WORKS !!! My Doubt are with 24V PULSE of 30MS !

Comment: See update to my answer re pulse trriggering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF your deice is a LT22222-**L** then

Interface for Model: LT22222-L:  then page 7 of the [data sheet](https://www.dragino.com/downloads/downloads/LT_LoRa_IO_Controller/LT22222-L/LoRa_IO_Controller_UserManual_v1.5.5.pdf) says the two inputs can withstand up to 50V directly.

➢ **2 x Digital dual direction Input (Detect High/Low signal, Max: 50v,** ...
➢ 2 x Digital Output (NPN output. Max pull up voltage 36V,450mA)
➢ 2 x Relay Output (5A@250VAC / 30VDC)
➢ 2 x 0~20mA Analog Input (res:0.01mA)
➢ 2 x 0~30V Analog Input (res:0.01v)
➢ Power Input 7~ 24V

---

In the [data sheet](https://www.dragino.com/downloads/downloads/LT_LoRa_IO_Controller/LT22222-L/LoRa_IO_Controller_UserManual_v1.5.5.pdf)

Page 34 shows how to connect inputs.

Page 23 shows how to set minimum trigger length

> AT+TRIG2 1,10

= Set channel  to input triggering on rising edge, with 10 ms minimum pulse.

Comment: Thx, my doubt is about the "duration of the pulse": 30ms. Is is short ? or ok to detect ?

Comment: With simple 24v generator, the inputs WORKS !!! My Doubt are with 24V PULSE of 30MS !

Comment: Ok, i missed that.. dont know how but this is ok. All things works now. thx you.